# Structuremap: Scan Folder, instantiate Class by name (For<ITest>.Use(string))

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm trying to use Structuremap, which gives me a hard time since the documentation on the structure-map-site is pretty old (most the time I work with the provided code, I get an obsolete-msg in VS...)

Anyway, I'm trying to provide something like this:

```
private static ITest GetInstance()
{
    return (new Container(x => x.For<ITest>().Use<Test2>())).GetInstance<ITest>();
}
```

This piece of code works fine, BUT now I'm trying to achieve the same thing without the Class "Test2" in this project.
My goal is:
I want to have a folder with all kind of .dlls, which provides ITest-Methods (like Test1, Test2, Test3, aso).
Structuremap should register those dlls (x.Scan(s => s.AddAllTypesOf)) and with a simple string I want to tell my application to use "Test2".

Here is my idea in code-form (not working):

```
public static class TestHandler
{
    static TestHandler()
    {
        Tests = new Container();
        Tests.Configure(x => x.Scan(scanner =>
                                        {
                                            scanner.AssembliesFromPath(@"TestCases");
                                            scanner.AddAllTypesOf<ITest>();
                                            scanner.LookForRegistries();
                                        }));
    }
    public static Container Tests { get; set; }

    public static ITest GetHandler(string handlerName)
    {
        return Tests.Configure(x => x.For<ITest>().Use(handlerName)))
.GetInstance<ITest>(handlerName);
    }
}
```

So how can I create an object, which I can pass then .Use?
And what variable would I have to pass anyway?

If I have to guess, I would say one of those:

- Full qualified Assembly Name
- Just the name of the class (which would be in this case Test2)
- AssemblyName.ClassName

I tried the WhatDoIhave()-Method, which gives me:

> ITest (smTests.ITest) TestExample1.FirstName, TestExample1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Configured Instance of
>   TestExample1.FirstName, TestExample1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   Scoped as: Transient

From that I'm quite positive that I have to use TestExample1.FirstName.
But how can I create an Instance in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with functionality for registering and getting all types by name:

```
public static class TestHandler
{
    static TestHandler()
    {
        Tests = new Container();
        Tests.Configure(x => x.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.AssembliesFromPath(@"TestCases");
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf<ITest>().NameBy(i => i.Name);
            }));
    }

    public static IContainer Tests { get; set; }

    public static ITest GetHandler(string handlerName)
    {
        return Tests.GetNamedInstance<ITest>(handlerName);
    }
}
```